# 12V to 24V booster circuit design

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter

I am trying to copy [this design for my circuit.](https://www.circuits-diy.com/12v-to-24v-dc-dc-converter-circuit/)

I have attached everything according to spec in real life on my circuit but what ever I try it won't output over 2.24 V. I have done a simulation in Multisim, too and it works fine.

The electrolytic capacitor is oriented in the correct way even if though it is not showing in the design as one.

Anything that I might have missed would help. I am desperate and I think I wasted money on this design.

Circuit design and my PCB design:

[image: My pcb design]

[image: My shcematic]

It is supposed to be a 12 V to 24 V booster but I keep getting 2.23 V.

Comment: Very poor layout. What's your switching frequency? What's the saturation current of the inductor?

Comment: https://gr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/652-SDE0403A-100M This is the inductor i got.

Comment: 1.4 A, should be decent enough. Hook up your oscilloscope to Q53 base and collector. How does it look?

Comment: What load do you have on the output? What is your power source? Is it current limiting? The original circuit shows a 100 uH inductor.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the poor layout which is obvious, there are couple of things that my eyes caught:

- Place a capacitor across the input regardless of what your supply is (battery, PSU, etc) because in any case you'll need at least one (simulation doesn't care because it uses ideal sources).
- Place a load resistance because this type of converters (especially if there's no feedback i.e. open-loop) generally don't like to be operated without any load. The output voltage can be anything, and you shouldn't rely on the 24V Zener here for output regulation.
- The switching frequency is about 125 kHz (correct me if I'm wrong) and the on-state duration for BD139 is about 4 microseconds. I'm not sure if BD139/140 can work well as a switch at this frequency (It works well in linear region at audio frequencies, though).

The maximum collector current for BD139/140 is ±1.5A and the peak collector current reaches to 4.8A. Considering the last two items above, the transistor might have died (gone shorted) already and this means that the input source might have been shorted by almost only the DC resistance of the inductor (~50 milliohms) or in other words, overloaded, which results in very limited supply voltage and current to your circuit. And in this case, the output voltage will be only 0.2V less than the input voltage. So if you are getting 2.2V then the supply might have limited itself to 2.5V due to an excess overload or a short.

Comment: "Apart from the poor layout which is obvious" ... How would you improve the layout?

Answer (score 2):

Correcting the inductor (-> 100 uH) and "changing" the mode of LM555 ...
And using a load of 100 Ohm, this can "work" with a BD139 ...
But it is not a "word" of stability versus the load ...

[image]

Comment: BD139 minimum beta gets woefully low at 1.5A. Needs a much smaller R5. Datasheet link in my answer.

Comment: Just to show "output" as in the link into OP question. Max output current = 300 mA.

Answer (score 1):

Complements Rohat's answer.

Inductor is marginal.
Somewhat faster clock frequency is in order BUT the 555 and transistor may both be unhappy.
[BD139 Datasheet here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bd139.pdf).   See table 2 page 4. Current gain could realistically be about (only) 20 at 1.5A.
Ibase here is about (12V-1V)/1k = 11 mA so Icmax about  200-300 mA . COULD be better, but probably not.

A suitable N channel MOSFET would make a vast difference.

NE555 is getting marginal at that frequency but OK if oscillating well.

[555 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf).
Change R69 to 100 Ohms.   555 will complain but is still in spec. Probably :-)

---

**MOSFET**

Any of [these](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoKwOwAYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAMxyIAsAnCALrEAOALlCAMocBOASwB2AcxABfYgDYE05CDSQseIqQrU4ADga6W7LpF4CR4qSFlaFSlQWJlIlAExg6cBlRDEnbuFTpeID60VPLevjSB0oghgYi6cnEIDHBgMIHBcHQQ4bR0AblZ6TIeYGBWMjHSThm%2BboF0WrSutbSJ3lQIWmBIHV1gNR1gNExDVFq9QVTDWgVTYAwIcBnTixXzi6PzEzlTTqsr%2B07Fe1ROYXtOcBdHTbt0MDrSnh1OTYN7TS%2BfWVGlXYcmhdGrRpFtbtEVv5pOt9tDwVR-H4oXRIcRUg9ESs6AgWh0cWBlvjcbD-LiPvt8gtsXQnJNUTBjidKbSPiC-Dd-NkiVNGD4ojEYHNKQxztjRTzGgsHuK3hlpNUtLCFW9wSqGPdHgxpLtztUPPL9cL1Sc4E4GDjJnrzetokt3ALXPBDZ05nQzgwtDcVTqMjAeog-jBHsCtOc9N5-UsKf7-Tzoq5A5G0tSStNOn60i5M7Secc6YwBUsYN87bRmYyEP6Gk1QX7grDGVL69qboztVswcGtBXzUmgu2zS24Ccyzph3nB42%2B%2BD29U-aErgvFcvzcuM5HQtM-QS2wTGwTO6U5ZGcdnTwgnDH8mLiIw-AMd7m4k7t6esrqhVlr1lvsc3PkGQTKkNzAYSQFLOUEFmlawHnkEcEUnBf5wcycGStc4xodG4LARuCFLP4Na0Mc0EAt4MJKhSlGzPKSo9nRSrevReZgm89I%2BFeWxmt0dJJFQizUaKWh-mxtEUcJo7-KJwmsdqwxFu43ryXMMAILS3TyvJzJgjqymerqYKeh8CaYlpnoyZ6cxljC5lelpszgvQCl3osjRWs5kp6dIzL0FeGSpAgAk1tKNyBdkAU9LSkXqX%2B4XCuFvnDEuMiLsGkUepFfgeYSZxZUR3ipH4vl0kKDQalktoYgqAWlSVVZ5h4xUZE1kTeE17otTQMrtd1NwdbCTXVr1I5so8uL9TQ-LeGGOpoecqYWFQjwwKB5q3gh624ea%2BFvDtuphh4aFnD1CEnaBJ15iJPiwtdhYzWcalAY9B2PUhy09EGWrPbGP1gBcGKMrdy3JM9swfIgyT3WdswXY5ilNGDjJIyhWEnA8OxoTeuH5LtszugduNIQBxO-kBAGgWpa4zWp%2BElm8EU00FKG08KPZBWhtOU1cSGMiOQF8xcrqLCcwvtNQ6lrIEwuPsQMvfDLcwy6LkvgXLqvrML8Fax8WsK5L00S3yPJa5rkv4cL4zS%2BbnY4mpuratMg0%2BelJTBtqLUu%2BsbgLGknurVa2oTMyQeg%2B1MKfXeqQan%2BQdlC19CDfQ4IpFWgeIMjrlCmHQSpyWCdVsKech34G3uqiQUJ4i6eIhSKSIrHfgFbnTf9U3jVN973SEVXOIJwqScKin1z9mWqT90O7Uj430RF%2B4astxqw%2BiunOiDd0vztRvIcb41G9bI0VzqS13QTCfOL9bMOc2tkgezPH6LBN8ZpuADN2TDCI7PHEN2mjd6wvw1D-PkwCDR3hhHIbiPgLSgL-owN%2B94f5qUmGae2SDLzoOstkZ4uxUFVnQW-NSXcSIAJ8IzCwal6gyEoZ2Js3tD5%2B2odAqIjInpMOGhQ-MLDjiliFC5EAjBCSnR8tkUcfCLgiIXpI203Z4zdlod0XYPleIsO6NZKoSjHiLWUfBBUiYog6mhnothFg5qljmtZOao5DESOePnGQdjrHLVsctb20c8QWBxIwTsPk6a4hBAYksSjfGWMQCZO0pYMSdQcfQAxGc4ieloAkpoADPSaXRGkiGaS5juCVKaNJ3FPSLGSUA8BExbIZKeCUnkuTPQlMKYsFBCQsluQSVLDJGoWn8PcBqN040H4gFyWiQZfMIZ81NF%2BFBX4xluGfqtDxX9GEjL0uVIRko3LpJGSOAB8AYDcXgLIOIezVpHIYM6EouhokjPkqc%2Bc6I9nf3RDqCMyygpsmuJsOI1RcRfLpBDZ4yInmWC%2BTqekFUTHXB1GyWsgLBnRDysQL099AhIr7oimE0V0X4xRRik4qKthIo4YSj4hLviErxTCE5WLHg4p7ASmEhysW%2BiZSShlZKGVzCRT5WlNVXIKj2TynkXL1j03BjyrYorAJYvHpUJYMDpWsq%2BLSzeIBKHZE5Z-ClQIGgQN5SAJFSS7zjRSvqmEG1uhbhrEfPFWZ7i6C9JMUVwVEXlGEdqKsEybwXFPlQ-V5QTFhnUusQN0NA0BtKiS0q3xBEb0CPARgiNEWlWsu60NPgflJrPCi60qysjer1PmhUQq3iR31SWu14wTxlrSYEUUrhvh1qlYM80WbiCNpOI29YdaTHdrZNCBAkxu1zG7RcbtPJu1dpcIykAdbHkzqncOqdHap2jqneOqdk7CSDpcDKpa1Qyptp3WNd427CSrsJOu4Y8Z3U0sRbDaNFVQ2wzxQ6klDqyUOs5UCI8sgqX6trLsJUJEUVKmKXenQgHQMksWHOnQchOUwaFTB4NMGCWLFhXBlVmG8XoYBkKDUkwdDnHWZ6W9%2BrRQVPIwJHDVNyqVq2K2blxBKFvAbQqSjjGGNFt2K2SeM6i1sdnrWot46i1dqLVxiBwmI7SZErJjtA9ROUVk5JsD-GwQ8aHh8VsYDVVnBEuJrs0mUjGfE5DBoDwB3QoDNpu0moBL%2BTbXadRSwlTCfiU5xAo72M8c6IamdfmGNnH%2BrW4L46uRBYeL5h42nlpqaOqKULDyjmCN83srtcWgu0B-Q1ULGoMtLxfDFhjZ5x1ni7WeErQUePZCrRaYYuweg8O%2BE1kswJHhmka5eEs6xWvOvAN1q5rXUSBGGzyYbWxWscKmx8KbJwpsXCm%2BN7rAriCteZa8rEZS5DLeOHcgbe35vdb1et9Z-LevHdtGlFr3W%2BOtdhY0aYJ3usDN0lWHLB6Z0b12PGmtbawziS%2B28WxYZfUWQYneFt%2BErJn3RNkJUDaHUSJvRDVL2mmiNFrY0uZ1xxYJGPm2mO6MGHDpjuO0UVzdBkNG0sBUcwAz8qiNg85AiOuOYG5CxbtPhkM7BDTke9JT4ezW7T3dDO7ui-p6Lo7I8ucj2W9cWHHOZMi8V32xEIXVcYv55SnXibldua1%2BOLXamGelOV4lk3N2PlS4%2BXLoy-PzOP0UbbjzzaLQZo515hoXIee08xyL2kwuBtB8lP4YyNOg%2B2mwQHkPOIbsxZyVcVEy2YtHZi1z1EHj7zuFm%2BpOakedSp51BdrPk31LXDz6-BP1x0YfmD1FEeNOoxc6jMtxkfERdBPpwMf643e%2BUbKDuyYQ-CSNd73difPed3zYn4tif-ed29Yn5N3vmyRw0AXqPwH2-Z8uHsmttfi-yir5cKb3v5vR%2BW-ABf74alpCMBaxft01ddNX73wsefZ-j91LvLWA-N%2BU6XWHgaKA2IBwB7o8YZqHCRCh8NOFoVsIuZyi0PQZypuyQeywBeyeeKQ06qQLgn2qBle8BteJBg%2ByQzQ8BHgXOugbUYBHgxCzUh%2BuIOcI4jAOcZQl41%2BfgqQCKN%2BWoI%2BaQOgkSrgI2h%2BWoboQus%2BWo8%2BWo-eWoy%2BWoq%2BeyA6UQTQq0s2aQiw4%2BKhmhKhEiKSSuZQKhihBGo2WhHixhGo0h%2BW5h2BOhooT%2B2BPejwO%2ByU%2Bw5hHoVUohkoXoiIy%2BmWnhsg4%2BoQGCh%2BoRZ2eiQR5EAi9qq2gyQUOg%2Bysg%2BE5cFk5h9W8%2B9W-e9WEqcgR8GRtIKCCwVYmhFo8ELGSuXYxyhRhsZQ5RWRz4h%2B5Ry%2B5Rq%2BCBghCB4%2BCBT%2BCBOR7o3sDBW2qqFBdR0o-W9R%2BQnRVIhRYhN%2BFovqkxseZQiAEON%2BRUkh2W-eqCACve9i6xxwB87i8%2BfgQ2uUTaAECwy%2BuOJxRmh%2Bduo2RRc6rgdID%2Bjxrxf8zQ42TxvWRR-YPsFU7xkEDQK0c6GMqCQJKqLxtOkJvxdIDoa2RRRhSJjWSJs2SJ9OSJ6QrAIAnA3AfAQgYgkgxAAAtDUNAIoFAAIAAK5qAOCUDYkSDmDyAUmCAAAm3AJJPQuweJRggQAAjhwAAJ7cC7DClsD4DcCYC4BoBMlAA)  may work adequately.

[Here](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRABYwBmABgE4IDKqwBWKkJ6t8zi71qz7M28Li1YAOYd3LTxYAOyKZLWHRABdAgAcALlBABlPQCcAlgDsA5iAC%2BBVopoIQySOmz4ipEFWU05BraIPqGJhY29gSwNPDQbqiYuATEkGT%2BknTZWroGkMZmVrYOILHSCe6eKT7pIABMYOSKdBwE9c2KVLztnVRiDX0qMc7KbSDO2XF8k4psfB3KlAud5D2DS0IxrWBg8mWjsPUrS8MUkspNJ84D9bSSYC7t92DHz9QtCyxUkk8N35J1ncwHQaGdgaD9hD6F89jRGP8IV87vUtoiqPVbhj6oosfULgjyFI6LBxiiLm9ERcyRiLut1CwaFDabjhBdcRpnvjYOCqN1YMz%2BZz-t0ul9%2BWc5kS%2BV9yPCgd14by5XtZfDKXc1iDZeR6n9yLBWKi0ZrdZS5GMsVrlXQOnweWDWAqgpjZbaznIQUS3fiFrAjpIof78cLMUcGMJibAEWH6q0-eGgcG6GjFHG5X9Y3R9g7lMKeU0nAnaOtyBjs7dg9GFqxHs57SmpAM5Jicu1a2CNbXa2cC81M93tdtvgO2I0a00cTW9UF7aN2HOwYoTUaaLW2cpWe3FlCjZ7pyTbkaSfnG5IV3H69u6GmD8vF4osnfwcfH3fQ8ejjX%2BlP2z-dz%2BH79LQ36kjGTrwkeKq7iqp4sL67ZyuOiE0PUXZrK6TA3vBNYYZKhYsLhijLIhxHocRZJOsRQK-HMty0UoCwMVCtF6kxnYxqxGqsWSrEmqxHq4j8-GdqGtEge04mluyqLsc4QaBpIGoCoGSaKSaKmSJWinguo%2BL6h0aHCmmDxsQQzhUKCym2pIZJ6YCfo2WiDKPHZNm6SS1APiSjnRusrCBPiMbqNGGmeZW2QPI52aUn2C7tOo2Zudm9KHEGkURYCobOMwwignImY5YxTDRv6Jo5WhCxzDQllsl6tzVSRDSNRqjVko1QKNeV1C-mUP6CFVPXZUoEnNSNrUjZ1I3lXqTp5Uochzk0-pVbNM1ruCrRdCaW3%2BAsW1lvt-jeu0B23AdUJbeup3%2BEaka-HAR1pjRmLzJJr35lQUisPRcaYQ0Sm2mJcajfiIOcSD-EYidAPQ-R0PgrZHQsdDYkYgFTHo5x6PcV9jwNoIT6SXjUO1gMUpGijAVo4ClLOPQs7E4C8NZQ%2BFyY%2BeuPnrxwlokSD38RhYlrKDgJlpxIvcc0upMdLvHS-RAVxkxAWjew%2BJNfiqu8arNGq-xquKzi3FGvekmmwMJagmiVvTAQtv7Fbrx8E74xO%2BsTs24EDBnE7jve8hfgB5SVt3C7AcewHvsB-7QSjVbPzh3H%2BZygFMYkiwl2GgN2yCD5p3Z-szQgm9DQkj9mYkr8O0CjCBcPPqcwMGSVe7PtOWXTloY3mulfOHdWEQd3-ct-3QI9znZddP9ZYGjV7d8n3fIathMqnV03QL-0W%2BbRvRcN2K6%2BKu3-qd-6w8Og%2Bcwn7e688qPPLjy0xVTwww%2B2n3WSXQ8xH7T-O0-02j-YULYcp-zhH-OU51AR1zLoCfGp14EImeofCYixybIz%2BAKZcpIZjI1TMjfYz0IzmQ6LaPBcdhC13UBQug6xiEEKCBgoIkpUQ0D%2BGmNOeClbcMCPaSgYFeEEIChggK%2B9lAITQVqe0AVmgyO9jI5GwgWyl0NGQxRGMYhGmumUbRsVtHjENLlLCC1nJOlUeYgYRiX7WJzITXshN8xSDblo0yMiHipTBNWVxQ5dFKQRP6JovY-L5lClg0KhjQr0lCs5PyVjSTxTKAk2JX14lfSLk3K4MQ5RBFCewP4acLT2kNIRGIJTonOFig6QxUpDplLAfUtcMxszKGaRcIh2YormU6XTTp9DOmpk6cZbMoI2kkIoNQjpWRyYjMlCMqZbYJhTA4VMXp%2BVmmQg2c7bpzctmlikPCZBFZJSmzpqbVMVEOFUTOc0cYOCskTB%2BqXe5zYfZyKwoELpjzlxEKcKwYyThYgzH%2BT9YFKZezZDoXc-53jHkkjORnGY0ZFk4JquaDksDcR6mQUcVCSL-B3P9EyJF0Z9Q%2B00RMQJ5p2SoNxNPPgWl4EMoFHKZltM2VrA5WiRljMQCMp0fyyk-Lxj8u5QKUFBB%2BX7H5cKRlQLJUClhXKoViqRWKvWHKsVWlXllVlYqs4cr9jq3ZQqrSwpjWctNdfEYYI6Fstvny7Baq6R8FkZQDV2CtVbgmb8FaVqPQHN6oy-6DxgJshxE0yVY5CQZQKbSWqUbATORJGuC5GEBgPEBAavYFKlKfIZTOWVs0-h5oHny2a4wgh7Bfk4II7NJWzXpCm3lSkVQFqQgW4M81iIZrDL2-0BqgolqCjGn4kjAaBj4LaJo4xp2WrQXQvFBA51ojnfsadFKN3mn5OwqdjQ5rLv3QMDdZwN3rsaPKkA07cGHrgOsa9q6L3Hovaei956lB-GndavqRwD1XsaA6-maZP0AefUoV9HwGyxCkAy5mla3myuZtyrSS6%2BUoZFShjVFwaHbGgxm9kCJAwSNg1kEtgZxmKXIZK0EN6%2BU0Y1TRg1NHpU0dlaCVBpHf7UcdAy9j5MnQMBLbaHkeVswweo5iFjlluUplQ3HQGU7-SGldYFWyinT7qZw1egdCJDwOr07Ogd96B2noHeugdwpDy-HU18qzhnxU2dMypGzlnz6fvPrp8%2BlJDzxkcPG8z6hV3nyc9mRT9NlEBTkwfbzDpCTsFtDFhpBwwSTuXQ6ILNxNO6doK05dOXLMYkenlgDU7ui8taESbLRJvNfVGXl-5NWYXAqrdl-567asFbzFBjapWGDtbfjMQsytl1IVPUhddSFLNylKVeygki6HcD4I8VEa9wCoXYM2KQaYETLfYPsXbCa1uojqUdp0AxdvvNO7y3bOibuUhu2iG7531tFgIDd4Uu3YWotWwaX1ZxPv3fW8pt7QPnuohE1hMq%2B2gc5n6uMXbDqEeVtsnAMHtYAkpv%2Bd1v92YlAIlrZ0qdSkHLLuJ-E1tp7bLnmEOmUaKVrPmUoIGWdKGrGY7pi17zdJ12gnnuZQFdsr28-vc3PmKiReQeXbaE72QOjrDrP6eXXjgdlAEa9igW3Kog9xH6tbOv-vK4%2B14q85w9j5z1wWJbxvAd0qV3Sx7xvnt0oN7iBnFuvkK6UsIPkagreu7tw57X2C-fOaD0TC3dWI87a8VRiP8OY8B-NwrxZdZwukIeA81PkaF1tu15lpgZWIcW8WiD3USfAo3m93WwHZecwCJL2ttYfPG97jwT2g31WHfVeewaB5LCWg19Clb3vHfozQ970b5oX5S9CWH7iPmxEQQ97pVbjsz2OwG6NGZNb7BM%2BvDgP9-fAolv75N7sADO3T-3dP-L0-j3T-ndP4fgD%2B3T8ff3185c-gX7n72Lfxo1Ob2H%2Bj%2BABz%2BZuJ%2BjQkev%2B4y0B1%2BkB4wIilCQBkBpYi8vm4A%2B%2BKYEBS%2B2BleyBII4ij4IBcA0eFWfwjwFWpBZYwSSkOiYiLYVuUK0OKYviFB-y5B9A-ypBDWjBuIHC%2B%2Bf6FBWKvBKuQhx%2BION436FBrQz22Qe0EhrQhBX0J%2B8ImKAmsCuwqEseXQcwGIJ%2BxI5BbAWQNSTQBo%2BhWQ0kZu9%2BUY5heBGBxIr%2BxI7%2B7BWCFwP01%2B7Bl%2B7BHhNG9o7Sbuuw7Bjhgm%2BhDAt%2BXB1hfWoRgcgRto8ObA0u5hJOGB2I8R5YOYtSHoWkfIr%2BHWJ%2B-Q8I%2BRsQ1%2BBRHoh4sKuwBRRckUWO5kNUWQAKsQo0s8SUJ%2BC2j%2BC2h%2BC25qcQEabRuo-B1s1%2BdCgcsi%2BkBMIK-RdoQBIxHRuoXRuor%2BIx7%2BUKhhUKl%2BUK8RUKCxicWEPwq21Mz0-Rh2uwdCrKMx0iFxZhVxCxDeuw8k9%2BcwXG5weYh%2BnCRCAh8RnCICmSj%2BXQJ29xZWwgi%2BoWQBfBfxgWJ%2BHI52AxtGk4cQ8usJBClw-2sJ%2B2AxJuxcPsS2GJcW54tGQGskb2GJiJeo3q8Jb4xJZJH2AxARtJO2tJ92tJpJTIQgIQYQBQEQxQ0QIAAAtMcJUFAGYAAK7eBpBkBsl2ClDxCgDmAAAmhgvJjwCIHJIAfAAAjnoAAJ6GAIjak6A4CGBoBYDIBSlAA) are some starting at $1.36 each in stock in 1's.

And at $1.93 in 1's in stock [this](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOTF2618L.pdf) will work very very well indeed.